# How to unzip all folders in an executable files in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, windows-7, settings

I have an executable file to install a software in Windows 7, which will unzip a number of folders inside it.

I tried with 1 computer and it worked. I tried with another computer and there left a number of folders that were not unzipped.

I assume this is some sort of Windows 7 security settings but I failed to google for a satisfactory solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would need more specifics about the different machines you are using it.

If it is a security issue, you will be able to successfully run it as an administrator. Do this by right clicking on it and selecting Run as administrator.

If the user you are using is not the administrator you will be prompted for an account and password, otherwise you will see just an extend UAC warning message you can accept.

The nature of the .exe could determine why it might not successfully unpack as well as the location the files are going to when being unpacked.